# How can I find if current time fall in time range in c#

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.

Any one knows how can I find if the current time fall in time range in c#.

For example: I want to check if the current time is between 12am and 4am.

I tried the following code but it gives me true statement when the current time is 6pm which is incorrect:

```
 if (DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Today.AddHours(0) && 
     DateTime.Now <= DateTime.Today.AddHours(4))
 {
     MessageBox.Show("time is between 12am and 4am");
 }
```

Please help me. thank you

Comment: Actually your code is correct if all used _DateTime_ parameters are related to the same day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(00, 0, 0); //12  o'clock am
  TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(04, 0, 0); //4 o'clock am
  TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
  if ((now > start) && (now < end))
  {
     MessageBox.Show("time is between 12am and 4am");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(DateTime.Now.Hour >= 0 & DateTime.Now.Hour < 4)
```

just tested

```
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Hour);
if(DateTime.Now.Hour >= 0 & DateTime.Now.Hour < 4)
    Debug.WriteLine("in");
else
    Debug.WriteLine("out");
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives wrong result. so if the time now is 8pm it still gives true statement

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Compare takes in two datetimes and compares them. If the first is after or later than the second it returns 1; if it's earlier than the second it returns -1. Otherwise it returns 0

```
if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Today.AddHours(0)) > 0  && DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Today.AddHours(4)) < 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("time is between 12am and 4am");
}
```